# load image files from folder without use opendialog in c#

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, image-uploading

I convert video to sequence of bitmap image and save as

pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"D:\pic\" + name + ".bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);

images names save as ( 0001 ,0002 ,0003  ,.............0200) in drive D folder pic

now  I have sequence of bitmap I need to load all image files except first image ,I can not

use opendialog because it 199 image i need to use in sequential, how can i do that in c#

such as:

// Load second image 
 // make some operation

//load third image 
//make some operation
.
.
.
.
//load  last image(199) 
//make some operation

Comment: `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles("*.bmp")`

Comment: please I need all images except first one image

Comment: Then use for(i=1; i<files.length; i++).....

Comment: Or even better,using a bit of LinQ DirectoryInfo.GetFiles("*.bmp").OrderBy(file => file.Name).Skip(1).ToArray()

Comment: @Steve,please can you explain more

Comment: DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(@"D:\pic\\*.bmp") will return an array of FileInfo which contains all information on a file. This is in the System.IO namespace. If you conbine that with LinQ, System.Linq - you can then order by name and skip the first entry and return the rest as an array of FileInfo[].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do :

Reference Linq:

```
using System.Linq;


FileInfo[] files = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo().GetFiles(@"D:\pic\*.bmp").OrderBy(file => file.Name).Skip(1).ToArray()
```

DirectoryInfo().GetFiles(@"D:\pic\*.bmp") will return an array of FileInfo which contains all information on a file. This is in the System.IO namespace. If you conbine that with LinQ, System.Linq - you can then order by name and skip the first entry and return the rest as an array of FileInfo[].

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void Load(string path) 
{

    foreach string s in path {
      using(Stream bmpStrm= System.IO.File.Open(s, System.IO.FileMode.Open ))
      {
         Image img = Image.FromStream(bmpStrm);
         b=new Bitmap(img);
         DoYourThang(b)
      }
}
```

Comment: @koki Ups! string, sorry my bad :S